# Bypass Proxy Server, ASP Website on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, proxy, ip-address

I've actually deployed my asp website on IIS and everything works well. I have done some reading on how to bypass the proxy server but i'm still unsure on how to do it. The reason why i want to bypass the proxy server on the network is to be able to read client's ip address (the ip address behind the proxy). Frankly speaking, i don't have much knowledge on this topic..

I read from MSDN that you can add in lines of codes into Web.Config file to bypass the proxy server. But i'm not sure what to type in or how to use this defaultproxy tag.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings)

Right now i'm only retrieving either 127.0.0.1 which is localhost or the machine's network external ip address which is not what i want..

Anyone can point me in the right direction to getting ip address behind the proxy? Appreciate any help please. Thank you..

Codes i have been experimenting to get client's IP address:

```
protected void getIP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
    String clientIpAddressHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName).GetValue(0).ToString();
    IP1.Text = clientIpAddressHostName;

    String clientIpAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"].ToString();
    IP2.Text = clientIpAddress;

    String ip = null;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
    {
        ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

    IP3.Text = ip;

    String ipNext = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();
    IP4.Text = ipNext;

    //String ipNextNext = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
    String ipNextNext = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"].ToString();
    IP5.Text = ipNextNext;

    String last = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.GetValue(0).ToString();
    IP6.Text = last;

    Label2.Text = getIPAdd();

    try
    {
        String externalIP;
        externalIP = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
        externalIP = (new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}")).Matches(externalIP)[0].ToString();
        Label1.Text = externalIP;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logManager log = new logManager();
        log.addLog("IP Add", "IP Add", ex);
    }
}

private String getIPAdd()
{
    System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
    {
        string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
        if (addresses.Length != 0)
        {
            return addresses[0];
        }
    }

    return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

Results,

[image: Results]

Requested Details:

[image: details]

Comment: As far I can understand you're talking about some reverse-proxy of nginx kind. The only way to see the real client IP then is to configure the proxy server to forward it to your app via an HTTP header. Do you know the name of the proxy server you use?

Comment: Hello again vorou, yeah i saw this nginx word somewhere a week ago.. How do i check that? Im actually having my final website presentation and what im gonna do is to publish the website on IIS then run it then back to my question getting the client's internal ip address on the SAME network. I was told by one of my peers that simply bypassing the proxy server will get what i want..

Comment: In case your IIS is on the same network as the machine you are accessing it from you should be able to access it directly (and see your actual IP within your app). Just be sure that you're accessing it by the IP of the machine where IIS is installed (if you're not sure you can terminal into it and run `ipconfig`; look for a line starting with `IPv4 Address`). Also, could you show the code you use to get the client IPs?

Comment: let me add some screenshots and code sample and probably necessary information @vorou thank you..

Comment: i've edited my question @vorou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used this to get the client IP address:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

As I can see you have that one in your code too, but it's commented out.
It worked for me:

[image]

Comment: hey vorou sorry i got carried away trying to solve something else. I still got ::1 which is localhost.. i checked my ipconfig in cmd it should be 192.168.1.118 but i'm not getting that..

Comment: what is the IP address of the machine where your app is deployed?

Comment: currently im using iis express to run my website as i havent deployed it on local iis.. i should be able to get 192.168.1.118 even though it's via iis express?

Comment: No, you won't see `192.168.1.118` when accessing it from the localhost. It would be `localhost` (or ::1), because it's where you came from. It would work fine if you access from the other machine, and since it a webapp I guess it would be the case most of the time, no?

Comment: so basically if vorou i were to run on local iis (iis the one that is provided by microsoft/windows the iis manager) on my machine i will get ::1/localhost? but if i were to run on my teammate's machine that is connected to the same network i would get a different ipv4 address?

Comment: @domster yes. And if a teammate goes to your app right now, he will see his IP.

Comment: okay.. sweet! i'll check back again if you dont mind vorou? thank you so much... my website project is due this monday.. desperation..